# PHP how to loop a script if $var is "empty"?

Tags: php, while-loop, var

I'm trying to loop the script below to get `$code` (from API) and if the result is empty then pause 5 seconds and redo the script and get `$code`

I want the script to `echo $code;` (if it have results or else redo the script)

```
do {
sleep(5);
$api = new DhruFusion();
$para['ID'] = $refid; 
$request = $api->action('getimeiorder', $para);
$code = $request[SUCCESS][0][CODE];

} while(empty($code));
echo $code;
```

Any other way to do this with PHP?
The script above stops without giving any results.

Comment: Are `SUCCESS` and `CODE` constants?  Or did you mean `$request['SUCCESS'][0]['CODE']`?

Comment: Rocket Hazmat: I write always: `$request[SUCCESS][0][CODE];` to get results. This is not the problem... problem to loop.

Comment: Unless you've declared `SUCCESS` and `CODE` as constants, that line is *incorrect*.  It works because PHP interprets undefined constants as strings (and throws a warning).  It may work, but it's bad practice.

Comment: Have you checked to be sure you're not exceeding the time limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no better way to loop over block until variable is given value.

It stops because one of followings happen:

```
$code is either:
- null
- 0
- 0.0
- false
- '0'
- array()
- ''

or it's endless loop and after dozen of seconds it just stops and returns nothing
```

Comment: You are right. When I see the source code for the result I see: `<style type="text/css"> .. </style>` I have tried `strip_tags($code);` but this dont remove CSS.